# transform a a text file into a binary stream?

Tags: c++

Is this code right?

If this is right, what would be the code for the opposite way like from Binary stream to text?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream in("in.txt");
   std::ofstream out("out.bin", std::ios::binary);

   double d;
   while(in >> d) {
      out.write((char*)&d, sizeof d);
   }
}
```

THIS is the input file

A
number of issues make the design of the video server, in a
video-on-demand application, difficult. First, a video server
needs to simultaneously provide video services to multiple
clients and guarantee the quality of service for each client.
Second, a video server needs to manage system resources,
including CPU/disk/memory, and schedule network activity so
as to utilize maximally the resources, while not overloading
the system. Third, a video server needs to be able to support
a variety of VCR operations such as playback, fast-forward,
slow-forward, pause, resume, indexing, and scrolling. Finally, a
user watching a video may change from one service to another
service—for example, from playback to fast-forward or from
playback to slow-forward. A video server should support
these dynamic service changes while efficiently using system
resources.

Comment: @Jeff He is reading doubles stored as text and storing them as binary. What's so hard to understand about that?

Comment: Deleted my original comment as it came across a bit harsher than I meant it!  What I find hard to understand is that we don't have an example of the format of in.txt and the title is confusing too.  Others seem to understand it, so maybe it's just me!

Comment: No, I don't have any assurance that he means that we think he means. He might be trying to write "od -x" for all I know.

Comment: @Jeff -- see OP's comment on my post. You were right, @Help19 wasn't trying to do what the code actually does.

Comment: It's important to us that you review all your questions and select the answers that solved them. There's a little check box on every answer, click on it to select the official answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct. For the opposite, exchange `write` for `read` and your are halfway there.

Just note that the encoding of `double` and it's size might differ on different platforms/systems/compilers, therefore using this type of storage for anything then a temporary stash is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this code right ?

That depends upon what you want it to do. What your program does is to read in a text file consisting entirely of the text representation of rational numbers and white space (e.g. `1.2 5 99.0`), and outputs a file consisting entirely of a binary representation of those same numbers.

Note that the details of how those numbers are represented is CPU- OS- and/or compiler-specific.

Is that what you wanted it to do?

> what would be the code for the opposite way

The opposite way would be to read in a file consisting of the binary representation of floating-point numbers and output a text file with the text representation of those same numbers. To do that, you would `ifstream::read` the doubles from an `ios::bin` file, and `>>` the numbers to the text file.

Note that the conversion won't be exactly. That is, you will almost certainly not get precisely the same output file as you originally started with, but rather one that is semantically equivalent.

Comment: no :( , I was to transfer a words and character and number to binary stream, for example if I want to transfer your answer above to binary what should I modify in my code

Comment: @Help19 In that case, I don't think you quite understand what you want to accomplish. What do you think a "binary stream" is? The sequence of characters in my answer, for example, *is* a binary stream -- no conversion necessary.

Comment: Ok sorry I made a mistake, if I want to change .txt ( which contains an article ) into binary what would be the code

Comment: @Help19 - The .txt file already has binary data in it. Is there a specific binary format you want it to be in (.DOC, for example)?

Comment: @Help19: What you need to do is go back and edit your question. Rather than showing code. Show us what the input file looks like and what you expect the output file to look like (or at least a description of what you mean by binary). Currently your description is way to vague and has no real meaning.

Comment: my program at the top it did change data to binary but it was transforming only double values, how would I do it for a paragraph that contains words, characters, numbers , etc ........ thanx in advance

Comment: @Help19 For the input you provided? There is no transformation. Simply copy the file, it already is binary.

Comment: so what are u saying if I have .txt file with an article in it, and it has words, numbers, characters etc ........ every thing is in binary excpet the numbers ( doubles ) ?

Comment: @Help19 Any file stored on the disk is entirely binary. Because it is digital. What you are talking about finding parts of the file that can be represented in a different binary format.

Comment: @Help19: I think this would be much easier if you could explain what exactly you want the output file to contain? Every file on your computer is stored as binary, so don't just say "I want the output to be the binary of the text file." Perhaps what you are really trying to do, is create a new text file filled with 0s and 1s so that you can read the text in its binary form?

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on what you mean by "binary stream".
The diference between a file opened in text mode and binary mode is that in binary mode if you read/write a "\r", "\n" or "\r\n" they are read/written literally, whereas in text mode the characters that make up the line end markers on your system are transformed into "\n", see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages)